# Unable to see google map in android app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created simple google map app. First it works fine, but after sometime it crashes and gives a simple blank map.

logcat errors:

> 07-20 05:34:48.656 11045-11145/com.example.faisal.fuel_share E/b:
>   Authentication failed on the server. 07-20 05:34:48.656
>   11045-11145/com.example.faisal.fuel_share E/Google Maps Android API:
>   Authorization failure.  Please see
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for
>   how to correctly set up the map. 07-20 05:34:48.656
>   11045-11145/com.example.faisal.fuel_share E/Google Maps Android API:
>   In the Google Developer Console
>   (https://console.developers.google.com)
>                                                                                           Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
>                                                                                           Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
>                                                                                             API Key: AIzaSyBp0yr4q6LOeUqPhOgH-1x70yjZRSs9W6c
>                                                                                             Android Application (;):
>   96:EA:99:F8:DA:73:5D:B7:6B:F0:62:1C:67:77:08:82:EB:68:62:7F;com.example.faisal.fuel_share
>   07-20 05:34:58.188 923-1718/com.google.process.gapps E/GCM: Missing
>   checkin config file 07-20 05:35:18.240
>   923-1718/com.google.process.gapps E/GCM: Missing checkin config file
>   07-20 05:35:58.300 923-1718/com.google.process.gapps E/GCM: Missing
>   checkin config file 07-20 05:36:28.408
>   960-12640/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find
>   provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings 07-20
>   05:36:28.764 10761-10761/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find class 'iua', referenced from method itz.a

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following [Android restriction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#key-std-details) for your API key in Cloud developers console

- **Package name:** com.example.faisal.fuel_share
- **SHA1:** 96:EA:99:F8:DA:73:5D:B7:6B:F0:62:1C:67:77:08:82:EB:68:62:7F

I suppose one of these values in your current configuration is not valid.